# 6999 Segmentation fault - C++

Tags: c++, aws-cloud9

This is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 5
```

The structure is defined :

```
struct Stack{
    int data[MAX];
    int top;
};
```

Checks whether the stack is full :

```
bool isFull(int tmpTop){
    return (tmpTop==(MAX-1));
}
```

Checks whether the stack is empty :

```
bool isEmpty(int tmpTop){
    return (tmpTop==-1);
}
```

Adds data to the stack :

```
void push(Stack *ptrStack, int n){
    if(isFull(ptrStack->top)){
        cout<<"Stack is full! Push aborted!\n";        
    }else {
        ptrStack->top++;
        ptrStack->data[ptrStack->top]=n;
    }

}
```

Gets the size of the stack :

```
int getSize(int tmpTop){
    return tmpTop+1;
}
```

Displays the stack :

```
void displayStack(Stack tmpStack){
    if(isEmpty(tmpStack.top)){
        cout<<"Stack is empty! Displaystack is aborted!\n";
    }else {
        for(int i=0;i<=tmpStack.top;i++){
            cout<<tmpStack.data[i]<<" ";
        }
    }
}
```

Returns the value in the stack :

```
int pop(Stack *ptrStack){
    int data = -1 ; 
    if(isEmpty(ptrStack->top)){
        cout<<"Stack is empty! Pop is aborted!\n";
    }else {
        data=ptrStack->data[ptrStack->top];
        ptrStack->top--;
    }
    return data;
}
```

The main method :

```
int main(){
    Stack aStack;
    push(&aStack,11);
    push(&aStack,22);
    push(&aStack,33);
    displayStack(aStack);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output : 
[image]

Comment: I don't see anything that initializes the `Stack`.

Comment: @FredLarson  well the stack is initialized in the main method.

Comment: No, it's not. It's instantiated, but not initialized. I added `std::cout << "Initial stack top: " << aStack.top << std::endl;` before the first `push()` call, and I got `Initial stack top: 6605868`

Comment: @GoodDeeds     top is initialized in the struct.

Comment: I would make `Stack` a class with a constructor, and make all the stack operations member functions. Better yet, use [`std::stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack).

Comment: your code is rather fragmented, which makes it difficult to read and impossible to copy & paste it without lots of manual editing

Comment: I second Fred. Not everything has to be OO, but this isnt even good functional style. Its a bit odd that you need to pass the size to  `isEmpty`,`isFull` and `getSize` to query the size. Those functions encapsulate nothing but can hide bugs.

Comment: Almost the entire code is very bug prone. 1) `isFull()`. what's happens if I call `isFull(7)`? 2) same for `isEmpty(-2)` 3) why `push` and `pop` are accepting pointer instead of reference?

Answer (score 3):

With your `Stack` declared as:

```
struct Stack{
    int data[MAX];
    int top;
};
```

... and instantiated as:

```
Stack aStack;
```

There is nothing that initializes the values of `Stack`, so the values you get are whatever garbage happens to be on the process stack. In particular, `top` is uninitialized and used to access the `data` array. This leads to your seg fault.

In fact, the compiler warns about this if the warning level is set sufficiently high. I get `warning: 'aStack.Stack::top' is used uninitialized in this function` when compiling your code.

Even if `top` were implicitly initialized to zero, as happens in some other languages, this would be incorrect. Your code uses a value of -1 for `top` to indicate an empty stack. You need to initialize it.

One way would be to add a constructor to `Stack`:

```
struct Stack{
    int data[MAX];
    int top;

    Stack() : top(-1) {}
};
```

Personally, I'd make it a full-blown `class` with all the operations as member functions.